# send a copy all requests to another server before nginx cache it

Tags: nginx, cache, forwarding

I Use Nginx to cache HTTP requests, this is my configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
    proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;

    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_cache_lock on;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header Front-End-Https on;
    proxy_buffering on;

    proxy_pass http://server;

}
```

But I Have another server for monitoring and statistical goals, I need to send all requests to that server before they cached by Nginx, is there anyway?

Comment: Nginx doesn't let you route the same request to two places, as far as I know. Does the statistical software act as a proxy? Can it read access logs?

Comment: It doesn't act as a proxy, but i think it's a good way to send logs for it :-?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the requests to monitoring / statistical server first, which sends them to this nginx instance with `proxy_pass` method.

Comment: it's not a good idea i think, it makes loading the pages really slower